# Interpreting Apache Spark stage progress bar in console while the job is running

Tags: apache-spark

Spark breaks and executes the code into stages.I also know that it is a progress bar which give information about staging part in Spark. What information do we get from the numbers in the following line in console when the job is running on cluster.

**[Stage 133:(4000 + 4) ====>    (1 + 1)/13000]**

Answer (score 2):

Progress bar indicates `[Stage 133:(4000 + 4) ====> (1 + 1)/13000]`

```
(numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks) / totalNumOfTasksInThisStage]
```

- Number of Completed Tasks = 1
- Number of Active Tasks = 1
- Total number of tasks in this stages = 13000

Please refer [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala) for the detail